# Python script to check for continous ping

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I am a fresher when it comes to Programming and my current work requires me to write a python script to continously ping a set of hosts and save the result to a CSV file with timestamps.

So my CSV file should fill up with logs when the host is down which i am tracking through "Request timed out"

```
import os
results_file = open("results.txt","w")
ip_list = []
len(ip_list)

for ip in range(1,11):
    ip_list.append("10.100."+ str(ip)+ ".1")

len(ip_list)

for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"ping {ip} -t").read() 
    print(response)
    if "Request timed out" in response:
        results_file.write(f"DOWN {ip} Connection Unsuccessful" + "\n")
    else:
        results_file.write(f"Works fine" + "\n")
```

I managed to figure out how to ping hosts and check if they are UP of DOWN. But continous ping does not fetch any result.

What Can i Do?

Comment: What do you mean by `continuous`? You loop over the IPs and check only once. You need a `while` loop (probably with some sleep inside) or a scheduler to do it "continuously".

Answer (score 1):

This works but im not sure what you intended with -t. 
I used -c so that it sends only 1 request.

```
for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.system(f"ping -c 1 {ip}")
    print(response)
    if response != 0:
        results_file.write(f"DOWN {ip} Connection Unsuccessful" + "\n")
    else:
        results_file.write(f"Works fine" + "\n")
```

Comment: Yea it works when i use -c or -n. But i need to monitor the ping constantly. Generally -t is the command we give on the cmd to let it ping continously. My script needs to alert me when it hits a timeout.

Comment: Just put a while loop over the for loop. With -t you just dont let it get a response because it does not finish the response. @kalpanaramesh